# Do I change the person in a quote talking about myself?

Tags: grammar

When someone says to me

> You definitely know what you're talking about!

and I'm proud of this and relay it to someone else, how do I quote this?

> My thesis subject is approved because I "definitely know what I'm talking about"!
>   My thesis subject is approved because "you definitely know what you're talking about"!

It feels wrong to change the person when you're quoting (a quote shouldn't be changed in the first place) but it sounds wrong if I take the literal quote.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your sentence is that it's two disparate things being jammed together inappropriately. Your thesis is approved because it's approved, not because your advisor said something to you.

Instead:  "My adviser approved my thesis subject.  She said, "you definitely know what you're talking about."

Comment: "Your thesis is approved because it's approved" that sounds like a non-statement to me. Given a scenario where the thesis advisor was on edge about whether or not allowing the subject until she realized I knew what I was talking about?

Comment: what I mean is that the spoken quote was not the reason for the approval, which is the sentence structure mistake that you have.  The quote is her comment ABOUT her approval.

Comment: I know that's what you meant, I'm just saying that it *could* be the reason. But the exact content doesn't matter -- it might as well say "because you've shown great promise in other subjects". This is a clear reason for approval so the reason of it being a problem with the sentence doesn't fit.

Comment: Let's try again:  the car stopped at the crossroads because "you're a very good driver!"   Can you see why that's a misplace construct?  Your passenger's statement about your skills didn't stop the car.  instead: He stopped the car expertly at the crossroads. "you're a very good driver!"

Answer (score 1):

When you quote someone in direct discourse, you use their words as they spoke them:

> My thesis advisor said to me, "**You** definitely know what **you**'re talking
>   about"!

When you report what someone said in indirect discourse, you have to shift person:

> My thesis advisor said that **I** definitely know what **I**'m talking about!

There are two ambiguities that might creep in.  The first happens in direct discourse because your listener or reader doesn't know the circumstances.  Suppose you and a friend were talking to your thesis advisor, and your advisor addressed your friend.  She would use the same pronoun, *you*, because she's talking to your friend.  Of course, when you report the statement in indirect discourse, you say

> My thesis advisor said that "**he** definitely knows what **h**e's talking
>   about."

Where *he* refers to your friend.  In direct discourse, you can make it clear that you, yourself are the person referenced by saying "said *to me*."

The second ambiguity only happens for a spoken sentence, when you don't have punctuation to help you.  The problem is that we often elide the relative pronoun that indicates indirect discourse:

> My thesis advisor said, "**You** definitely know what **you**'re talking
>   about"!

and

> My thesis advisor said **you** definitely know what **you**'re talking
>   about!

sound the same, but the *you* in the second sentence refers to the person you're reporting to.

Comment: exactly.  this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not set on quoting it, I would just say "my thesis adviser said that I definitely know what I'm talking about."

If it really matters, you could try something like:  my thesis adviser said that "[I] definitely know what... [I'm] talking about." but that gets pretty weird.

I can't think of a good reason to use such a nonspecific quote unless in casual conversation or email, in which case you can do whatever you want without worrying about it.